# passing an object pointer to a function

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I'm trying to pass the value contained in the object obj to the function `addnode` but I get a code blocks error that it can't convert `obj` from `mos*` to `mos`. How could this be rewritten to pass a pointer to the function `addnode`
The code is as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct mos
{
    int x;
    float y;
    mos * next;
};

void addnode (mos);

int main()
{
    mos * obj = new (nothrow) mos;
    //Check for proper memory allocation.
    if (obj == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\nProblem assigning memory.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n Memory well allocated.\n Result is: " << obj;
    }

    addnode(obj);
    return 0;
}

void addnode (mos * head)
{
    //code that adds a node to the last node in the linked list.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function declaration and definition don't match. If you want to pass a `mos*`, change the declaration to:

```
void addnode(mos*);
```

At the time the compiler was seeing your call to `addnode`, it had only seen a declaration that takes a `mos` rather than a `mos*`.

Comment: That worked perfectly well thank you. I didn't expect the problem to be in the function declaration. Finally do you know how I could rewrite my main function to make it more efficient? If you do, could you please post the code it in your reply?

Comment: @MosesNjagiMwaniki more efficient? in terms of how to implement a linked list? or just your code there?

Comment: @MosesNjagiMwaniki There's really nothing inefficient about it. I don't know your reasoning for using `std::nothrow` and I also recommend not doing `using namespace std;` ever. Don't forget that the standard output stream may not necessarily flush automatically, so you might want to do `<< std::flush` (or `<< std::endl`, which will give you a new line too).

Comment: @MosesNjagiMwaniki a hint - in terms of a list - is it better to move through them all or go straight to the last? If the latter how could you do that.

Comment: @sftrabbit I've used nothrow to check whether a new object has been created. Though no concrete steps would be taken after that. I'll look for alternatives for using namespace std;

Comment: @MosesNjagiMwaniki The better alternative is to properly qualify your names (use `std::cout`, `std::nothrow`, etc.).